# Susy 2 - Cannot get working

Tags: ruby, windows

I am a 57yr old female self taught with little base knowledge I am a web designer not programmer so I really struggle with the techy side.

I have installed Ruby into `Program Files (86)` then had to uninstall as I read about spaces in folder names. Reinstalled at the top of `C:`

I installed the Dev Kit at top of `C:` then ran `ruby.dk.rb.init` and `ruby.kd.rb.install`

I have got my head around Bundler (I think)

I install gems at the top of C:

My config.rb at the top of the project says

```
require susy
```

I have a `Gemfile` at the top of my project with a `Gemfile.lock` file

Here are the contents of the `Gemfile.lock` file:

```
GEM
remote: https://rubygems.org/
specs:
breakpoint (2.4.2)
sass (~> 3.3.0)
sassy-maps (< 1.0.0)
chunky_png (1.3.1)
compass (1.0.0.alpha.19)
chunky_png (~> 1.2)
compass-core (~> 1.0.0.alpha.19)
compass-import-once (~> 1.0.3)
json
listen (~> 1.1.0)
sass (>= 3.3.0, < 3.5)
compass-core (1.0.0.alpha.19)
multi_json (~> 1.0)
sass (>= 3.3.0, < 3.5)
compass-import-once (1.0.4)
sass (>= 3.2, < 3.5)
ffi (1.9.3-x86-mingw32)
json (1.8.1)
listen (1.1.6)
rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
rb-kqueue (>= 0.2)
multi_json (1.10.0)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.4)
ffi (>= 0.5.0)
rb-kqueue (0.2.2)
ffi (>= 0.5.0)
sass (3.3.7)
sassy-maps (0.3.2)
compass (~> 1.0.0.alpha.13)
sass (~> 3.3.0.rc.2)
susy (2.1.2)
sass (~> 3.3.0)
PLATFORMS
x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
breakpoint
compass
susy
```

When I use PrePos it compiles Susy1 mixins fine but will not compile Susy2 mixins

At the command prompt if I run

```
<Path to folder> sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

I get

```
Sass is watching for changes
error Line 3 File to import or not readable: compass

Load path **C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/bundleproject/sass (DEPRECATED)**
```

At the command prompt if I type

```
<Path to folder> compass watch
```

I get

```
Compass is watching for changes
```

then nothing happens after a change is made to the .scss file

I just don't know what to do next any advice would be so appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use Compass then the GUI app [Scout](http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/) may be what you are looking for.
It comes with its own self contained ruby environment.

I have only used it on OS-X myself but there is a windows install guide [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/sass-on-windows-with-scout-app/)

Comment: I am in no way affiliated with Scout, its still kinda awesome though.